How can I switch between high-current 240V devices in my workshop?
I am the only one working in my shop. I do not have to worry about anyone else switching power cords etc.
I have a double 50 amp breaker, and only one 240v 50 amp outlet connector.
I have to manually unplug my Air Compressor, in order to use my Hobart MVP 210 welder.
I would like to install a two way switch that gets power from the Double 220v 50 amp breaker. And have two individual 240v 50 amp outlets, that would get power from the two way switch.
This way I could leave them both plugged in, and which ever i need to use, I just throw the switch to the left or right, (left side for the welder, right side for the Air Compressor).
I've searched for a switch, but I do not know the correct key words to search for the proper switch... and that is if there is a switch capable of this.
Can anyone lead me in the correct direction to achieve my goal... if it is even possible, and within code?

How far from the panel to the existing receptacle and the planned second receptacle? Because if it isn't far and you have 2 empty spaces in the panel, you could use a breaker interlock.

Seems like a switch isn't needed; just put in a second outlet, and plug both devices in. When you use one of them, turn it on. When you're done turn it off. Just like you'd do with multiple outlets on a 120 branch circuit.

Is there some additional constraint that prevents you adding a second outlet? It is normal practice that services and feeders are over-subscribed (within limits, of course) precisely because of the reason you identified: equipment will not operate concurrently.
It seems reasonable to wire an additional receptacle to your existing 50 A circuit. Reasonableness not withstanding, there seems to be some disagreement as to whether or not Code prohibits this arrangement (there and there, for instance). Your AHJ is the official who has final say, and you certainly could ask.
In any case you can add a new circuit to power a new outlet. This might ripple into adding a subpanel or enlarging an existing one, and you'd be well advised to follow the load calculation procedure to determine whether addition of a new circuit will cause the upgrade to ripple upward.
In my opinion it's worth checking because outlets that "just work" seem even better than having any kind of transfer switch.

The switch you want exists, you just aren't looking in the right place
Switches bigger than 30A generally require something heftier than a wall-switch mechanism, so you need to look for something heftier than a wall switch.  The usual form this comes in in the US is called a "safety switch", and double-throw safety switches are also a thing, so one of those with a rating upwards of 50A will do the trick.  Note that you want a non-fusible safety-switch -- you don't need the fuse holders in your application, and most fusible safety switches are set up for source transfer instead of load switching.

You need a 60 amp, 2 pole, 2 position, selector switch or drum switch. Sometimes it is also called a motor reversing switch. Fairley common, but I would suggest looking for it from a commercial supplier like Grainger.

Thank you, I Google your kwy words and this was the result. It states its a 3 phase connection. The picture looks exactly like what I had in mind. But I need a single phase connection.  KEYMOO 63A Rotary Changeover Switch with Exterior Box,660V 3 Position 3 Phase 12 Terminals,2-Way 3NO 3NC Universal Selector Switch, Cam Switch IP65, CE 63/D303.3D https://a.co/d/03unT1k3

This might be a better option. Looking at the internals of it... it looks like the type of switch I had in mind. But dang! They want $433 for it.    https://www.zoro.com/square-d-nonfusible-safety-switch-heavy-duty-240v-ac-2pdt-30-a-nema-1-92251/i/G2026893/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping%20feed&utm_content=free%20google%20shopping%20clicks&campaignid=21118514345&productid=G2026893&v=&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwps-zBhAiEiwALwsVYeg6pa_W6A2sklGQu-1gVOy4uOBvirJUZbObK5x5gZeTMuq3Zp7fwxoCoFkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Another option is a breaker interlock. This is a sliding metal gadget that fits around two breakers in a panel so that only one of them can be on at a time. They are required for generator or other backup power to avoid backfeeding, but they can be used for any purpose where you want to make sure that only one breaker of a pair is on at a time.
Obviously this only works well if the new receptacle is a short distance from the panel, because wire can be expensive. It also only works if you have two spare spaces in your panel. You may need to do some rearranging so that you can have the two double-breakers next to each other. The exact layout will vary, and even within a panel brand/type you need to make sure you get an interlock designed for a pair of double-breakers and not for "double breaker plus main breaker".
